# OpenGL ES2.0 flamework(include loading model)

Tags: java, opengl-es-2.0, android-2.2-froyo, collada

I must make OPEN GLES2.0 on android2.2.
So I want flamework(include loading model).(COLLADA or OBJ)
Please let me know framework of it or tool.

Answer (score 1):

NV_EVENT?

http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra/news/nvevent-framework-fast-and-efficient-android-opengl-es-20-applications